# Selenium / lxml : Get xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, selenium, lxml

Is there a `get_xpath` method or a way to accomplish something similar in selenium or lxml.html. I have a feeling that I have seen somewhere but can't find anything like that in the docs.

Pseudocode to illustrate:

```
browser.find_element_by_name('search[1]').get_xpath()

>>> '//*[@id="langsAndSearch"]/div[1]/form/input[1]'
```

Comment: Did you look at all the supported locators in the official docs at http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.html ? There is an `xpath` locator too. Edit: Looks like you want to do the reverse - given the DOM element generate and XPath, right? I am not aware of such functionality, but the Selenium IDE plugin http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/ is doing some kind of DOM to XPath conversion so you might want to look through its code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no unique mapping between an element and an xpath expression, a general solution is not possible. But if you know something about your xml/html, it might be easy to write it your own. Just start with your element, walk up the tree using the `parent` and generate your expression.

Answer (score 6):

This trick works in lxml:

```
In [1]: el
Out[1]: <Element span at 0x109187f50>

In [2]: el.getroottree().getpath(el)
Out[2]: '/html/body/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/p[4]/span'
```

See documentation of [`getpath`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#generating-xpath-expressions).

Answer (score 3):

Whatever search function you use, you can reformat your search using xpath to return your element.  For instance,

```
driver.find_element_by_id('foo')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*@id="foo"')
```

will return exactly the same elements.

That being said, I would argue that to extend selenium with this method would be possible, but nearly pointless-- you're already providing the module with all the information it needs to find the element, why use xpath (which will almost certainly be harder to read?) to do this at all?

In your example, `browser.find_element_by_name('search[1]').get_xpath()` would simply return `'//*@name="search[1]"'`. since the assumption is that your original element search returned what you were looking for.

Comment: I think you need to include brackets:    '//*[@id="foo"]'

Comment: AttributeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute 'get_xpath'