# Is there a way to pull the XPath from an element on selenium

Tags: python, selenium

So I need to pull the XPath of an element for some code and can't find a way to pull it using

```
Comment = find_element_by_link_text(str(Comments))
CommentXPath = Comment.???
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium / lxml : Get xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788059/selenium-lxml-get-xpath)

Comment: Can you please share what your overall goal is? - in selenium xpaths are used for identifiers, but by the definition of what you are trying to do, you've already identified your object. If we know why, someone may be able to help in another way

Comment: Is this solve your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411765/how-to-get-an-xpath-from-selenium-webelement-or-from-lxml