# Python selenium wait until an element located not by xpath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, lxml

I am scraping a webpage in multiple pages, pressing certain buttons will advance to the next page, but all the pages share exactly the same url, means most elements I have scraped aren't visible until certain buttons of the same type before them are clicked, thus trying to click them will raise the following error:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div class="answer"> could not be scrolled into view
```

The elements are all of the same class, and they are all children of instances of another class, each of the parent classes have multiple instances of the child class.

To find the elements, I use two times `.find_elements_by_class_name()` method:

```py
lists = []
for i in Firefox.find_elements_by_class_name('parent'):
    lists.append(i.find_elements_by_class_name('child')
```

There is exactly one element in each of the sublists that needs to be clicked, the element is determined by its attribute and identified using list indexing, so I have absolutely no idea what its xpath is.

Each of the elements aren't visible until the preceding element is clicked, so wait for them is a must to avoid `ElementNotInteractableException`.

I am using the following syntax:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(Firefox, 3)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

And I need to find the xpath of an element located using the aforementioned methods, unfortunately Selenium doesn't support this natively.

But I have found a trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20026066/16383578):

```py
In [1]: el
Out[1]: <Element span at 0x109187f50>

In [2]: el.getroottree().getpath(el)
Out[2]: '/html/body/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/p[4]/span'
```

So I think, if I can build lxml tree from selenium page source then somehow convert selenium elements into lxml elements then it can be done, though I don't know exactly how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this (maybe you need to use `contains` for `class`):

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//*[@class="parent"][{index}]//*[@class="child"][{subindex}]')))
```